# Different time on each boot

Tags: boot, mount, systemd, fstab, disk

With the `dmesg` command I noticed that the disks are mounted at different times for each boot. Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot Windows.

Fast boot:

```
$ dmesg 
...
[    5.870528] EDAC amd64: F15h detected (node 0).
[    6.490309] EXT4-fs (sdd2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    6.634475] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    6.658732] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
...

$ systemd-analyze blame 
5.711s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                     
2.039s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                             
1.938s dev-sda1.device                                                
1.270s snapd.service      
...
```

(sdd2) (sdb2) (sdc1) are mounted quickly.

Slow boot:

```
$ dmesg
...
[    8.596732] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   12.256446] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   12.259373] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   12.309078] EXT4-fs (sdd2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   12.353819] audit: type=1400 audit(1637523250.977:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=792 comm="apparmor_parser"
...
    
$ systemd-analyze blame
10.746s dev-sda1.device                                                
 5.778s plymouth-quit-wait.service 
...
```

(sdd2) (sdb2) (sdc1) are mounted with a delay of almost 4 seconds.

Maybe I did something wrong in the `/etc/fstab`?

```
UUID=c5a40bed-b039-496e-abb8-3e783bcb0fa5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

# pucciaMOD DISCHI

UUID=14b461cc-aaf4-45c3-a31a-1d56b4b4aaa2  /media/Archivio  ext4 rw,defaults  0    0
UUID=40d01381-4e47-45ad-b644-ccc5c09faeba  /media/Mia  ext4 rw,defaults,  0    0
UUID=75a8a386-71b2-451f-b4cc-f69f5ce4f779  /media/Partizione1  ext4 rw,defaults  0    0
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to always mount the disks at the same time as in fast boot?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: I installed Ubuntu in dual-boot with Windows. The partition where Windows is installed is not mounted in /etc/fstab because it is not needed. If it helps, Windows starts very rarely. Months can go by without using it.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Your problem may not be related to Windows, at least not in the way I was thinking.